# Two Variables, One Horizontal Row, Different Styles for Each Variable

Tags: css

In the code below, both `$dt` and `$points` display on one horizontal line, which is what I want.  However, I would like these two variables to have different styling.  I would like the keep the `sitename3name` stying on `$dt` but change the styling on `$points`.

`sitename3name` has a width of 585 pixels.  I would like `$points` to appear flush against the right side of this 585-pixel area, and have a different style than `$dt`.

**EDIT:** The `.pointlink` style is not applied in the code below, because I'm not sure how to and make it do what I want.

How can I do this?

The styles are also listed below.

The code:

```
`echo '<div class="sitename3name">Submission date: '.$dt->format('F j, Y').''.$points.'</div>'`;
```

CSS currently applied to both, which I would like only to be applied to `$dt`:

```
.sitename3name { 
            width:585px;
            margin-left:23px;
            margin-top:0px;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: normal;
            height: 25px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-top: 0px;
            background-color: #CAE1FF;

}

.sitename3name a{ 
            position:absolute;
            color: #004284;
            text-decoration:none;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bold;
            height: 25px;
            padding-right: 5px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-top: 2px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;

}

.sitename3name a:hover{ 
            position:absolute;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            background-color:#FF0000;
            text-decoration:none;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bold;
            height: 20px;
            padding-right: 5px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-top: 2px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;

}
```

CSS I would like to apply to `$points`:

```
.pointlink { 
            float:right;
            margin-right: 0px;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:bold;
            padding-top: 2px;
            padding-right: 3px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            background-color:#004993;
            color:#FFFFFF;


}
```

Comment: I don't see anything called `.pointlink` in your HTML. What is the issue you're having? Please show us your HTML output instead of the PHP that generates it. You can't "style PHP variables", you can only style HTML.

Comment: The HTML output is just text and numbers.

Comment: So, no HTML? Just text? Then why are you calling it point**link** and showing styles for an anchor when there are no anchors in your code sample?

Comment: Actually, I'm going to change it to a link when I figure out how to control the positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually have an element with class "pointlink" in your markup. If you wrap the date (i.e. your "`$dt` variable") in an element too, you can style it separately when you're ready.

```
<div class="sitename3name">
    Submission date: 
    <span class="date">
        <?php echo $dt->format('F j, Y'); ?>
    </span>
    <span class="pointlink">
        <?php echo $points; ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wesley_murch/Eh7HZ/2/